# erasing a shape in java

Tags: java, drawing, jpanel, erase

i am trying to draw circles that appear every second, i was able to do so but how do i make the old shape disappear ?

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
  try {
    while (true) {
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(500*Math.random(),500*Math.random(), 50.0f, 50.0f);
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(circle);
        ga.setPaint(Color.green);
        ga.fill(circle);
        ga.setPaint(Color.red);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) 2) `paint(Graphics)` Don't code AWT in this millennium.  If custom painting in Swing components, use `paintComponent(Graphics)` 3) `while (true)` Don't start an *infinite loop* in the paint method.  4) `Thread.sleep(1000);` don't *wait* in the paint method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the background color and use it to cover the old circle with a background-color circle.

Comment: i did just that i redrew the circle with a white fill thank you

Comment: If your background color isn't white you can use `ga.getBackground()` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `super.paint(g);` first thing in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method here is to simply call `g.clearRect(WIDTH, HEIGHT);` up the top of your `paint()` method.